# How can I display a transparent PNG on Delphi 2007?

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-2007, timage

The TImage control doesn't support PNG. Is there some third party component that will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully used the TPaintBox component with the DevExpress TcxImageList which supports PNGs, and then drawn the images in the OnPaint using the list's facilities. Worked well. DevEx also have a TcxImage, but I've not tried that.

Answer (score 10):

Try [PngComponents](http://www.thany.org/download/14/pngcomponentssetup.zip) - as long as they are available...

A D2009 version can be found [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26127)

**EDIT**
On Google code the following link for older versions of Delphi:
http://code.google.com/p/cubicexplorer/downloads/detail?name=PngComponents.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 3):

Try [Delphi PNG and MNG libraries](http://delphi.pjh2.de/articles/graphic/png.php/)

Answer (score 2):

[GraphicEx](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=33) will give you support for both png's and many other formats.

Comment: I think this is the best way to handle it.  Just put it into the uses clause and it works.

Answer (score 1):

DevEx  TCXImage component support PNG straight forward.

```
CXImage1.Picture.LoadFromFile(myimage.png)
```